# Edit PostGIS views in AutoCAD Map

Tags: postgis, autocad

I have a database on PostgreSQL/PostGIS (9.5/2.3), and even if the final concept is to use it in QGIS (software that I have a good knowledge about), for now most of the people in the office are working with various versions of AutoCAD Map.

I defined a frame in which only the datas relevant to the area of interest are being loaded in QGIS through the use of views, and rules to allow their "updatability".

I would like to be able to do the same in AutoCAD Map, but it seems that when I load a view, it is automatically non-updatable, whereas with a regular table the update is possible. Does anyone know why it is like that, and, even better, how to do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Is the primary/unique key known to autocad map? It may not recognize a unique key from a view so maybe you have to set this manually in autocad.

Comment: @tilt Thank you for the clue. Unfortunately it doesn't seem I can't define a primary key in AutoCAD, nor a primary key in a PostgreSQL view. So it is not possible...